# Does there exist a positive integer which is a power of two, such that by rearranging it's digits we can get another power of two?

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

Does there exist a positive integer which is a power of two, such that by rearranging it's digits we can get another power of two?
I know a quite good solution, that involves working with sum of digits, which is the same after rearrangement and seeing it in modulo 9, ... e.t.c
Maybe someone can come up with another method of solution, which is shorter.
Anyway want to see any other methods than my.

Comment: If you already know a solution, why don't you show it?

Comment: The mod $9$ solution is one or two lines, tough to improve on that!

Comment: Ok, if you've got such an integer then after the rearrangement its sum is the same so the same is remainder when divided by 9. When we see powers of 2 : 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256. Lets see corresponding remainders by 9 : 2 4 8 7 5 1 2 4 e.t.c. The cycle is obvious(and it is easy to prove it).The length of the cycle is 6. So if we permute a number we will get something bigger in at least 2^6 = 64. So it has another number of digits in it. But it is impossible as it is a permutation. So there's no such integer

Comment: $1,2,4,8$ are four possible solutions.

Comment: He probably meant rearrange in the strict sense.

Comment: The single digit examples 1,2,4,8 can't be rearranged to get "*another* power of two", @AsafKaraglia . If the identity rearrangement is allowed, then any power of 2 is already an example..